# Qt.AlignTop/VCenter/Bottom attributes of QTextEdit don't work at all. What do I have to do?

Tags: python, qt

I've just upgraded Qt to version 5.15.1.
So now I can see the attributes Qt.AlignTop/VCenter/Bottom in my VSCode.
But when running my code, any of them doesn't work.

> OS: Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS
> Language : Python 3.5.2 64bit
> VSCode version : 1.39.2
> Qt version : 5.15.1
> Qt Designer version : 4.8.7

< test.ui >
[test.ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srQkQ.png)

< test.py >

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

form_class = uic.loadUiType("test.ui")[0]

class MyWindow(QMainWindow, form_class):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # self.move(1300, 500)
        # self.move(0, 0)
        self.pb_left.released.connect(self.doLeft)
        self.pb_center.released.connect(self.doCenter)
        self.pb_right.released.connect(self.doRight)
        self.pb_top.released.connect(self.doTop)
        self.pb_middle.released.connect(self.doVCenter)
        self.pb_bottom.released.connect(self.doBottom)
        
    def doLeft(self):
        self.te.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        
    def doCenter(self):
        self.te.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
    def doRight(self):
        self.te.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        
    # Doesn't work ----------------------------------------------
        
    def doTop(self):
        self.te.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

    def doVCenter(self):
        self.te.setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)

    def doBottom(self):
        self.te.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        
    # ------------------------------------------------------------

    def keyPressEvent(self, a0):
        if a0.key() == Qt.Key_Q:
            if a0.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier: self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MyWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setAlignment): `Valid alignments are Qt::AlignLeft, Qt::AlignRight, Qt::AlignJustify and Qt::AlignCenter (which centers horizontally)`.  So you can only align the text horizontally -- not vertically.

Comment: If you need to align vertically your best option is probably to place the `QTextEdit` in a `QVBoxLayout` or similar.